# How can i program a recursive coin change in c++?

Tags: c++, recursion, coin-change

I'm trying to build a recursive call for coin change in c++ . i tried most of the algorithm on the internet but it doesn't seem to apply with vector or it doesn't out the sums of the coin used. Can anyone help me understand what the recursive function has to call? So my algorithm doesn't give me the minimum number of coin used and i don't know how to save the coin used.

```
int coin(vector<int> denom, int s,int N)
{
    if(N == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(N < 0 || (N > 0 && s < 0))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return min(coin(denom,s - 1, N), 1 + coin(denom, s,N-denom[s-1]));

}


 Input a value N:
    Input: 40
 Input how many denominations:
    Input: 3
 Denominations #1: 
    Input: 5
 Denominations #2:
    Input: 20
 Denominations #3:
    Input: 30

 Output:
 Minimum # of coins: 2
 Coin used: 20 + 20
 Don't want:  30 + 5 + 5
```

Comment: What is `s` and `N` in this context? Can you please define the problem a bit clearly, as to what you want to achieve?

Comment: s is size and N is the number. I want the function to give me the minimum # of coin   and also produce the result of the coins used

Comment: I don't see any arrays here.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: array size is not needed because `vector` has in built function `size()` which does that for you.

Comment: Please also post sample input and desired output to make the problem clear.

Comment: sorry how can i add the input and output?

Comment: @Darkflame leave your code in the question and ask specifically what issue you're having.

Answer (score 3):

Some points to consider:

- Firstly, there is no need to send the number of denominations i.e. `s`
  as an argument to the `coin` method as long as a `vector` is being used, because `vector` has inbuilt `size()` method which does that job for us.
- Secondly, **to save the solution** you need another `vector` of `int` named `solution`, but this `vector` is just to keep a record and has nothing to do with the actual recursive implementation and hence, it is defined as a global variable. Alternatively, you could pass it as an argument by reference to the `coin` method too.
- Thirdly, the denominations entered by the user should be sorted before passing them to the `coin` method. For this, I have used the [sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) method from the `algorithm` library.

What the recursive algorithm basically does is:

- At each step, it considers the largest denomination `d` (last element in the sorted denomination `vector` `denom` like `denom[denom.size() - 1]`) which is then removed from the `vector` using [pop_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/pop_back/) method of `vector`.
- Using `d` we find `count_d`, which is the number of coins of denomination `d`, used in the solution. We get this by simply applying a div operation like `N/d`, which gives the **Quotient**.
- Then `d` is added to the `vector` `solution`, `count_d` number of times.
- The recursive call, adds `count_d` from this iteration and recalls `coin` with the reduced denominations `vector` `denom` and **Remainder** of the amount `N` using `N%d`.

See [Quotient and Remainder](http://www.kidport.com/REFLIB/Math/Division/QuotientRemainder.htm) for clarity of what div `/` and mod `%` operators do.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

vector<int> solution;

int coin(vector<int> denom, int N)
{
    if(N <= 0 || denom.size() <= 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int d = denom[denom.size() - 1];
    denom.pop_back();

    int count_d = N/d;

    solution.insert(solution.end(), count_d, d);

    return count_d + coin(denom, N%d);
}

int main()
{
    int N,s;
    cout<<"Input a value N:\nInput: ";
    cin>>N;
    cout<<"Input how many denominations:\nInput: ";
    cin>>s;
    vector<int> denom;

    for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        int d;
        cout<<"Denominations #"<<i+1<<":\nInput: ";
        cin>>d;
        denom.push_back(d);
    }

    std::sort(denom.begin(), denom.end());

    int minNoOfCoins = coin(denom, N);

    cout<<"\nOutput:\nMinimum # of coins: "<<minNoOfCoins;

    if(minNoOfCoins > 0)
    {
        cout<<"\nCoins used: ";

        for(int i = 0; i < solution.size(); i++)
        {
            if(i > 0)
            {
                cout<<" + ";
            }
            cout<<solution[i];
        }
    }

    cout<<endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: hey, thx for posting this! However the code doesn't give the minimum coin used; Ex: if we make N = 40     and denom   = { 5 , 20 , 30}.... t he result gives me 30 + 5 + 5   when the minimum should be   20 + 20.... Thx though for the help

Comment: Yeah you are right this is a greedy algorithm, for that you will have to use a brute force or dynamic programming algorithm.